# python - regex parsing log

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

i have the following log line i want to parse

```
<log pos_start="40652288" end_position="40689664" log_type="1" length="37376" block_id="4024" block_position="18"/>
```

i am using python regex, this is what i did so far

```
regexParse = re.match(".*pos_start=(\d+).*end_position=(\d+).*log_type=(\d+).*length=(\d+).*block_id=(\d+).*block_position=(\d+).*",StatelogLine)
start_position = regexParse.group(1)
end_position = regexParse.group(2)
```

i am getting the following error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

anyone has any ideas what is the problem

Comment: Pretty simple: [your regex does not match your string](https://regex101.com/r/aW9aR7/1) - as a side node, the dot-star soup (`.*`) would be very inefficient as well. Additionally, why not use a parser instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could parse the line such as you get both key and value: [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ3jI9/3)

`(\w+)="(\d+)"`

and if you need you could also create a dict out of it:

```
import re

s = '<log pos_start="40652288" end_position="40689664" log_type="1" length="37376" block_id="4024" block_position="18"/>'

matches = re.findall(r'(\w+)="(\d+)"', s)
#[('pos_start', '40652288'),
# ('end_position', '40689664'),
# ('log_type', '1'),
# ('length', '37376'),
# ('block_id', '4024'),
# ('block_position', '18')]

d = dict(matches)
#{'block_id': '4024',
# 'block_position': '18',
# 'end_position': '40689664',
# 'length': '37376',
# 'log_type': '1',
# 'pos_start': '40652288'}
```

Comment: I like this one (+1) - straight forward. Better use a parser though.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple: your [regex does not match your string](https://regex101.com/r/aW9aR7/1) **because of the not specified double quotes**, that is. If you add them, [your regex works](https://regex101.com/r/aW9aR7/2).
As a side node, the dot-star soup (`.*`) is very inefficient. Why not use a parser instead?

Consider the following code with `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
string = """<log pos_start="40652288" end_position="40689664" log_type="1" length="37376" block_id="4024" block_position="18"/>"""
xml = BeautifulSoup(string)
print xml.log["pos_start"]
# 40652288
```

You can access your element like an array afterwards, no druidic regex needed. Have a look at [their homepage and documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: what do you mean by using parser?

Comment: @danieltheman: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: @danieltheman: I have added some example code, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You regex is not correct. You need to escape double quotes to make it a successful match.

```
.*pos_start=\"(\d+)\" +end_position=\"(\d+)\" +log_type=\"(\d+)\" +length=\"(\d+)\" +block_id=\"(\d+)\" +block_position=\"(\d+)\"
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the double qoutes

```
regexParse = re.match(".*pos_start=\"(\d+)\".*end_position=\"(\d+)\".*log_type=\"(\d+)\".*length=\"(\d+)\".*block_id=\"(\d+)\".*block_position=\"(\d+)\".*",s)
```